# Кривая Безье на ActionScript

Tags: алгоритм, flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы срезать у прямоугольника угол.
а конкретно:
есть 3 точки, между которыми нужно "нарисовать" кривую Безье второго порядка.

Но, собственно, визуализировать это не нужно.
Нужно только получить координаты нескольких точек, или хотя бы одной, той, что лежит посередине кривой Безье.

Работаю на AS3 (Flex). Проблем с тем, чтобы нарисовать эту кривую, вовсе нет. Но ума не приложу, как получить точки.

Если можно, был бы очень благодарен за рабочий код, но не откажусь и от ссылок, что почитать.

Замечу, что изучать этот материал до той степени, чтобы написать функцию самому от начала до конца, я не стану, т.к. мне это нужно только в 1 месте.

Никого не прошу писать эту функцию за меня (если, конечно, нет желания), т.к. понимаю, что это не ваши заботы; но если кто-то решал подобную задачу и уже писал/находил какой-то код по этой теме, то прошу выложить...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Непонятна задача. Есть абстрактные три точки, через которые нужно провести плавную кривую? Или есть прямоугольник и нужно найти некие три точки - каким условиям удовлетворяющие?

Comment: нужно найти координаты хотя бы одной точки, лежащей посередине кривой Безье...

Comment: Что дано? 4 точки: две опорные, две контрольные?

Comment: прочитайте внимательно!

"есть 3 точки, между которыми нужно "нарисовать" кривую Безье второго порядка."

Comment: На Википедии довольно доходчиво описано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с кривыми пользуюсь вот этой библиотечкой: https://code.google.com/p/bezier/

Код я взял из примера №6, он есть внутри проекта с примерами, вряд ли он заработает сразу, но должен дать понимание как получать точки на кривой:

```
var start:Point = new Point(100,300); // начальная точка
var control:Point = new Point(300, 300); // точка управления, куда стремиться искривление
var end:Point(700, 500); // конечная

var bezier:Bezier = new Bezier(start, control, end); // строим модель кривой, без представления

var position:Point = bezier.getPoint(0.5); // получаем координаты точки на середине кривой
// если нужно первая четверть то 0.25, начало 0, последняя точка 1
```

Comment: во, именно то, что я искал!(если заработает, конечно)) )

Спасибо!

Comment: На Здоровье! :)